# Android Layout, positioning elements next to eachother

Tags: java, android

I am busy designing my first app in android but I am having some problems.

I have created this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.mfr.calculatorapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:text="123"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:textSize="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button_1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:textSize="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button_1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

But the two Buttons appear underneath each other and not on top of each other, I know that if I change orientation to horizontal that I will be able to position it next to each other but I want to be able to span a textview over the top.
What do I do?

Regards

Matt

Comment: Can you show us an image like you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a relative layout.  You will see the below code didn't need a lot of extra attributes to pull this off.

Notice that the buttons now have three additional attributes.

- andoid:layout_below="@id/"  :  positions the element under another element
- android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing : if the above mentioned element is not present, align with the parent
- android:layout_alignParentLeft : allows you to position one button to the left and one to the right

**UPDATE** use android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView" to properly align your second button to the right

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.mfr.calculatorapp.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:text="123"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:textSize="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button_1"  
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:alignParentLeft="true"
/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:textSize="@dimen/number_button_size"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button_2" 
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```